# Update data inside class based detail view

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I want to let the user edit their inputted data from the detail view directly. The data the user have previously entered should also be displayed.

This is my detail view right now:

```
class GeographyDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DetailView):
    model = Geography

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(GeographyDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = GeographyForm()
        return context

    def post(self, request, pk):
        post=get_object_or_404(Geography, pk=pk)
        form = GeographyForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            geo = form.save(commit=False)
            geo.student = self.request.user
            geo.save()
            return redirect('geography')
 
    def test_func(self):
        Geography = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == Geography.student:
            return True
        return False here
```

Right now when I submit the form, instead of updating the data, a new one is created. I also don't know how to prefill the form with the data that was previously entered.

This is my forms.py file

```
class GeographyForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Geography
    fields = ('title', 'rep1', 'rep2', 'rep3', 'rep4', 'rep5')
```

This is my html template

```
<div class="container px-5">
<h1>{{object.title}}</h1>
<div>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        {%csrf_token%}
        {{form}}
        <button type="submit">Bekräfta</button>
    </form>
</div>
<hr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you here describe is in essence an [**`UpdateView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView). I would suggest that you use this with:

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

class GeographyDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Geography
    form_class = GeographyForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('geography')
    template_name = 'some_template.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(
            student=self.request.user
        )
```

This should be sufficient: it will pass the object to edit as `object` to the context, and the form as `form` to the rendering context.

The form should be submitted to the same view as this one and will redirect to the `geography` view in case the form is valid.

The `get_queryset` filters on the `student`. This means that it will return a HTTP 404 response in case the user that aims to edit the object is not the `student` of that object.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked, now the data gets updated instead but the data previously entered does still not show up, do you have any clue why?

Comment: How do you render the form? Can you edit the question with the Django form and HTML counterpart?

Comment: Added both now.

Comment: @AdrianMahdavian: you removed the `get_context_data` override, right? Because that is no longer necessary: Django will construct a form object with the instance and pass it to the context as `form`.

Comment: Oh I did not do that. But now when I do, the updateForm no longer shows up at the detail view...

Comment: @AdrianMahdavian: sorry, I mean't `get_context_data`? Normally it automatically passes the form as `form` to the template, so you can render it with `{{ form }}`.

Comment: Yes that is fully removed!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241314/discussion-between-adrian-mahdavian-and-willem-van-onsem).